# Maven Problems: Project build error: Non-resolved parent POM

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework:gs-spring-boot:0.1.0: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.6.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.6.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to authenticate with proxy and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Answer (score 1):

This might occur when the version you are using is unstable. Downgrading the version helped me and might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1) spring boot required java 8

```
java -version
```

to check java version  if

it is not something like this

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

then set java home path to jdk 8

and then run the same command to check.

2) Place `settings.xml` in .m2 folder

3) run bellow maven force update command

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: Spring Boot doesn't _require_ JDK 8. They are using Spring Boot 1.3. We used Spring Boot 1.5 with JDK 7 just fine.

Comment: Hey Chloe tried above steps and these are in working states.